# Take value if ID is the same

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2019

I need a formula to take a value if the ID is the same. Example image:

[image: Example table]

I have table with ID and Value.

In first row is 22222 and 15. If I change 15 (in first row) to 55, then the value in table for ID 22222 will change to 55.

Next, if I change 22222 and 15 (in first row) for 33333 and 99, then the value for ID 33333 will change to 99, but previous change (22222 and 50) will stay in table.

How can I do it?

Comment: This requires VBA and a [Worksheet.change event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Change)

Comment: I also think VBA is needed to fulfill your needs. After you change the ID and Value of the first row, the value of the cell referenced by the formula also changes, and it is impossible to retain the data that was previously changed.